# Invert an RTC GPIO on ESP32

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I am developing a battery powered device that will wake when a sensor switch goes high. Now I also need the device to go back to hibernate mode and wait for the sensor switch to go low. I am using the ESP-IDF. I have configured the ext_1 wakeup pin(s). The device wakes as expected.

The problem is that the pin is set to wake on going high. When the device goes back to sleep, the pin will still be high and I want to detect when it goes low. My first thought is to invert the pin - so low reads as high. I don't see a way to do that in the ESP-IDF.

I do not want to use the ULP for this as it draws too much current in sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a single pin to wake up, just change the level to ESP_EXT1_WAKEUP_ALL_LOW before going back to sleep.  If you need it to wake when any of multiple pins goes low, and/or need it to sleep with multiple wake pins in mixed states, ULP is the only option I came up with.  The problem isn't just with getting it to wake on any low, it won't go back to sleep when any are high -- by definition with the only other ext1 level choice of ESP_EXT1_WAKEUP_ANY_HIGH.

Comment: Thanks Mark. That's what we were finding.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [gpio_wakeup_enable() documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/gpio.html#_CPPv418gpio_wakeup_enable10gpio_num_t15gpio_int_type_t) you can request wakeup from light sleep on either low or high GPIO value by specifying `GPIO_INTR_LOW_LEVEL` or `GPIO_INTR_HIGH_LEVEL` as the value of parameter `intr_type`.